# how to close iframe if iframe page src redirects to specific url

Tags: javascript, html

i am using a simple iframe html code where i am embedding the jitsi meet url. now the problem is after finishing a meeting with jitsi it redirects to its close3.html page. i dont want to show this in my iframe. i want to close my iframe when it redirects to close3.html page. i have tried with sandbox. but after using sandbox camera and microphone access turns disable.

here is my iframe code

```
<iframe
       title="Open identification process"
       src="https://meet.jit.si/4b7562c798c20e3dd523b2298cad5327"
       frameBorder="0"
       width="600"
       height="800"
       allow="camera; microphone"
       id="iframe"
       onLoad="alert('Test');"
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

You will face [the Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) when you try to do.

> You can't access an `<iframe>` with different origin using JavaScript,
> it would be a huge security flaw if you could do it.

Even so, you could use that method:

```
document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href
```

**[Further Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)**